# Ionic 3 - Cannot navigate to any page that calls HTTP in its constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on an Ionic 3 project, and have been trying to use Ionic Native's HTTP (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/). I started out by creating a separate provider that used HTTP, but any page that imported the provider wouldn't load / be navigated to. I didn't understand this, so I tried to use it directly on the page itself, instead of creating a provider. After troubleshooting, I realized that the issue occurred whenever HTTP was called in the constructor. There is no error being thrown when I run it with console logs.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocationTracking } from '../../providers/location-tracking';
import firebase from'firebase';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-ad',
  templateUrl: 'ad.html',
})
export class AdPage {
  postId = 0;
  imgURL: any;
  testToBeSent: any;
  childRef: any;
  zipCode: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public LocationTracking: LocationTracking, private http: HTTP) {}
```

My goal is to be able to navigate to any page that uses Ionic 3's HTTP plugin, or any page that uses a provider that uses Ionic 3's HTTP plugin.

Comment: Please post your code and described what your goal is.

Comment: you need to manually install ionic native components, they do not come built in. Also you might want to try `import { Http } from '@angular/http';` instead of native http.

Comment: Make sure that you follow the step : 

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-http
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/http

Then Add this plugin to your app's module in providers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating into the documentation and the GitHub page for that project, it looks like the project hasn't been updated in a year and was geared around Angular 1.x based on the guide on their page.  So those import statements probably won't work.

Look at this part of the docs : https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP#usage. That's angular 1 syntax.  The part of the docs that say 'not angular JS' might be more relevant to your issue.  'This plugin registers a cordovaHTTP global on window'

Edit: I looked at the docs from the Ionic page and they're more specific to angular 2, nonetheless the project they point to on GitHub hasn't been updated in a year and looks abandoned with outdated docs but ionic's updated their docs but still points to the old project.  Anyways, I'd still vet that the library a bit if I were you.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, and I didn't check into that. Will be more diligent in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you importing http from that library?
Use '@angular/http'

```
import {
    HttpModule,
    Http,
    Headers,
    RequestMethod,
    RequestOptionsArgs,
    Response,
    ResponseContentType
} from '@angular/http';
```

Also constructor is not place to put HTTP calls.
Have a look at both [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and [Ionic life cycles](https://saniyusuf.com/ionic-by-component-page-lifecycle/)
I would put it in  ionViewDidLoad() preferably.

Comment: Good idea - I may try Angular's http instead of ionic's. Someone else recommended that as well.

Also, I have not had the chance to make any http calls because I cannot load any page that has http on it! However I will try to put it into ionicViewDidLoad() if I get it to work.